# Importing Maxmind CSV into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, csv, csv-import

I have downloaded the `GeoLiteCountry` CSV file from Maxmind - http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry. Using the format given to me as standard (so that this can become an automated task) I am attempting import all the data into a table.

I created a new table `IPCountries2` which has columns exactly matching the columns provided:

```
FromIP       varchar(50),
ToIP         varchar(50),
BeginNum     bigint,
EndNum       bigint,
CountryCode  varchar(50),
CountryName  varchar(250)
```

Using the various chunks of code I could find, I was unable to get it working using the field terminator and row terminator:

```
BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '","',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

The result of this was a single row inserted, all correct except the last one had overflowed with the next lines (presumably the whole database if I didn't have a limit). Also, the first cell had a quote at the start.

I looked around and found something called a format file (never used these). Made one which looks like:

```
10.0
6
1   SQLCHAR     0   50  "," 1   FromIP      ""
2   SQLCHAR     0   50  "," 2   ToIP        ""
3   SQLBIGINT   0   19  "," 3   BeginNum    ""
4   SQLBIGINT   0   19  "," 4   EndNum      ""
5   SQLCHAR     0   50  "," 5   CountryCode ""
6   SQLCHAR     0   250 "\n"    6   CountryName ""
```

but this errors on the bigint lines:

> Msg 4867, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (overflow) for row 1, column 3 (BeginNum).

It does that 10 times and then stops because of maximum error count.

I was able to get the first method working if I took it into Excel and re-saved, this removed the quotes. However, I don't want to rely on this method as I want this to update automatically every week and not have to open and re-save manually.

I don't mind which of the two methods I use ultimately, just so long as it works with a clean file. I had a look at their documentation but they only have code for PHP or MS Access.

**Edit**

Some lines from the CSV file:

```
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
"1.0.8.0","1.0.15.255","16779264","16781311","CN","China"
"1.0.16.0","1.0.31.255","16781312","16785407","JP","Japan"
"1.0.32.0","1.0.63.255","16785408","16793599","CN","China"
"1.0.64.0","1.0.127.255","16793600","16809983","JP","Japan"
"1.0.128.0","1.0.255.255","16809984","16842751","TH","Thailand"
"1.1.0.0","1.1.0.255","16842752","16843007","CN","China"
"1.1.1.0","1.1.1.255","16843008","16843263","AU","Australia"
"1.1.2.0","1.1.63.255","16843264","16859135","CN","China"
"1.1.64.0","1.1.127.255","16859136","16875519","JP","Japan"
"1.1.128.0","1.1.255.255","16875520","16908287","TH","Thailand"
```

**Update**

After some persisting I was able to get things working 95% with the original method (without the format document). However, it was changed slightly to look like so:

```
BULK INSERT IPCountries2
FROM 'c:\Temp\GeoIPCountryWhois.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '","',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '"'
)
GO
```

Everything goes in the right fields as they should, the only issue I have is in the first column there is a quote at the beginning. Some sample data:

```
FromIP  ToIP    BeginNum    EndNum  CountryCode Country
 "2.21.248.0    2.21.253.255    34994176    34995711    FR  France
 "2.21.254.0    2.21.254.255    34995712    34995967    EU  Europe
 "2.21.255.0    2.21.255.255    34995968    34996223    NL  Netherlands
```

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of data from the CSV file?

Comment: Ah yes how silly of me, find in my OP

Comment: In your original bulk insert, you specify FIELDTERMINATOR as '","'.  Why the double quotes around the comma?

Comment: If I don't specify quotes I get **Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 3 (BeginNum).**. Presumably this is because it's trying to insert a quote symbol into a field not able to handle one (ie. bigint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Success. [Searching around](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/10/04/bcp-bulk-insert-format-file-escape-a-quote-more-to-the-point-loading-quoted-csv.aspx) and some help from [another forum](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1271531-391-1.aspx) finally got me to my solution. For those in need of a similar solution, keep reading:

I ended up using the format file method - whether it would be possible to use fieldterminators and row terminators I'm not sure.

My SQL code looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    DuffColumn  varchar(50),
    FromIP      varchar(50),
    ToIP        varchar(50),
    BeginNum    bigint,
    EndNum      bigint,
    CountryCode varchar(50),
    CountryName varchar(250)
)

BULK
INSERT #TempTable
FROM 'c:\Temp\GeoIPCountryWhois.csv'
WITH
(
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\Temp\format.fmt'
)

INSERT INTO IPCountries2 (FromIP, ToIP, BeginNum, EndNum, CountryCode, Country)
    SELECT FromIP, ToIP, BeginNum, EndNum, CountryCode, CountryName FROM #TempTable
```

As found in my research, it was necessary to have a useless column which simply captured the first quote.

My format file looks like:

```
10.0
7
1   SQLCHAR     0   1   ""      1   DuffColumn  ""
2   SQLCHAR     0   50  "\",\"" 2   FromIP      ""
3   SQLCHAR     0   50  "\",\"" 3   ToIP        ""
4   SQLCHAR     0   19  "\",\"" 4   BeginNum    ""
5   SQLCHAR     0   19  "\",\"" 5   EndNum      ""
6   SQLCHAR     0   50  "\",\"" 6   CountryCode ""
7   SQLCHAR     0   250 "\"\n"  7   CountryName ""
```

To note, despite eventually being stored as a BIGINT, BeginNum and EndNum are both passed in as SQLCHARS, otherwise the insert does an odd multiplication on the numbers (something about reading it as bytes rather than digits, I didn't entirely understand it).

And that's about it. The last thing to automate this script fully is to truncate the table first so as to clear out old records. However that might not be to everyones needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command.  All I did is remove the double quotes from your FIELDTERMINATOR:

```
BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Your data fields are actually terminated by commas, not commas wrapped in quotes.  I also suggest building a staging/import table match the datatypes of your source file exactly, which in this case would look like:

```
FromIP       varchar(50),
ToIP         varchar(50),
BeginNum     varchar(50),
EndNum       varchar(50),
CountryCode  varchar(50),
CountryName  varchar(250)
```

Your source data for BeginNum and EndNum is actually string, not bigint.  You can convert this data once you have it imported into your staging table.

Comment: Please see my comment on the OP, sadly this doesn't help

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @sql varchar(1000)
declare @filename varchar(100) = 'C:\Temp\GeoIPCountryWhois.csv'

set @sql = 
'BULK INSERT geoip FROM ''' + @filename + ''' 
WITH
(
CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
ROWTERMINATOR = ''' + char(0x0A) + '''
)'
exec (@sql)
```